# Formula within a textbox in a form showing as "#Name?" when opened

Tags: ms-access-2010

I have a Microsoft Access 2010 database program that let's users update certain information within based on permissions. There are 2 versions, one for each facility. I recently added a new form to the 2nd facility by copy/pasting the form from the 1st file and then adding the necessary queries.

Everything worked great except for one column that contains a RowNumber formula for displaying the, you guessed it, row number. This was working in the 1st file and I have made sure that every property matches exactly, but the image below is what I get when I try to open the form. As if to add more chaos to the mix, the 1st file started showing the same results as well, despite working perfectly fine before and me not even touching that specific text box.

I have Googled this issue but have not seen anything with this specific result. Can anyone explain what this means?

[image]

Column in question (where formula is located):

```
Name: Text57
Control Source: =RowNum([Form])
Visible: No
Datasheet Capt: Seq
```

Column in question:

```
Name: Label58
Caption: Text57
Visible: Yes
```

Answer (score 0):

Row numbering on the fly normally is completely academic in Access as it has no meaning. The row number on a form has no relationship to anything in the data, and can change if the underlying data changes in any way.

The RowNum() function is not inbuilt in access as far as I can tell, so I'm not sure how it could work.